# How can I convert my device token (NSData) into an NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, nsstring, nsdata

I am implementing push notifications. I'd like to save my APNS Token as a String.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)newDeviceToken
{
    NSString *tokenString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[newDeviceToken bytes]]; //[[NSString alloc]initWithData:newDeviceToken encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", tokenString);
    NSLog(@"%@", newDeviceToken);
}
```

The first line of code prints null. the second prints the token. How can I get my newDeviceToken as an NSString?

Comment: What is the output of the second `NSLog`, the one that prints `newDeviceToken`?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305225/best-way-to-serialize-a-nsdata-into-an-hexadeximal-string/35730103

Comment: do NOT use description

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Note - This will not work when compiling with the iOS 13 or later SDK**

use this :

```
NSString * deviceTokenString = [[[[deviceToken description]
                         stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<" withString: @""] 
                        stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString: @""] 
                       stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];
        
NSLog(@"The generated device token string is : %@",deviceTokenString);
```

Comment: It seems a bad idea to use description : nothing ensures that later version of iOS will not change the implementation and result of this call.

Comment: Indeed, this is a really bad idea.

Comment: @madewulf very nice of you to point out how it's such a terrible idea to use description.. it would have been even nicer if you have suggested an alternative

Comment: The solution here under with [deviceToken bytes] fits the bill.

Comment: Why would Apple change this, its ok to use this kind of implementation.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16411517/1555903

Swift version: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24979958/1555903

Comment: Turns out as of Swift 3/iOS 10, .description on a device token returns "32 bytes". So yeah, don't use this.

Comment: This method no longer works, use the new updated version using bytes.

Comment: As of iOS 13, the behavior of `[NSData description]` has changed and this code will generate an invalid token string.  Please use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372815/how-can-i-convert-my-device-token-nsdata-into-an-nsstring/24979958#24979958)

Comment: Indeed, here are some thread in Apple forums describing the `description` change in iOS 13.

[here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/119111) and [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/117545)

Comment: Developers shouldn’t have relied on a specific format for an object’s description.As it is can change in any version.

Comment: Some trainee used this exact same reply in our app earlier this year, and building on iOS 13 just broke it. I don't understand why this was ever upvoted, it's clearly an ugly, brittle hack.

Comment: This is not the right solution as already pointed out. The "description" of an object is not consistent and should not be used as a serialization method.

Comment: This is the first result on Google when searching "push token to string"... This really should not be the accepted answer. It also breaks on iOS 13 with apps built with Xcode 10.3.

Comment: Not worked in ios 13. Vishnu prakash answer is perfect.

Comment: @madewulf Was right 4 years back.

Answer (score 272):

If anyone is looking for a way to do this in Swift:

Swift 3 introduces the `Data` type, with value semantics. To convert the `deviceToken` to a String, you can do as follows:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    let token = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined()
    print(token)
}
```

Old answer using `NSData`:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    let tokenChars = UnsafePointer<CChar>(deviceToken.bytes)
    var tokenString = ""

    for i in 0..<deviceToken.length {
        tokenString += String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [tokenChars[i]])
    }

    print("tokenString: \(tokenString)")
}
```

Comment: Error on the first line inside the function :
Cannot convert expression's type 'UnsafePointer<Void>' to type 'ST2'

Comment: @Cherif: Just updated the code for the latest version of Swift

Comment: Why does this have to be so complicated, what's wrong with the OS giving us a string since that is what everyone needs ?

Thank you for this solution.

Comment: I refactored: `let token = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined()`
http://qiita.com/mono0926/items/3cf0dca3029f32f54a09

Comment: I don't recommend using .description as that is not guaranteed to be stable. Check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372815/how-can-i-convert-my-device-token-nsdata-into-an-nsstring/39754930#39754930

Comment: NB @MasayukiOno code should be enclosed in an extension of Data i.e. extension Data { let token = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined()  }

Comment: I would have gladly stayed in Swift 2 for time reasons but was forced to migrate, then there's all these new issues to consider, wish Apple would respect its developers.

Comment: following my test in the answers the fastest as of 05.12.2017 is deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02x", $1)})

Comment: what does this format '02.2' do? it seems work without them.

Comment: Can you explain what does `"%02.2hhx` do?

Comment: Those who choosing between what to use, there is a sample: `var token = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined()` // gives like 7cbac37b00275289a2e21c357241b615e6939e0dda7daf4feb537fce6ee61760; `token = deviceToken?.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})` // gives like 7CBAC37B00275289A2E21C357241B615E6939E0DDA7DAF4FEB537FCE6EE61760

Answer (score 164):

Someone Helped me with this.I am just passing along

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken {

    const unsigned *tokenBytes = [deviceToken bytes];
    NSString *hexToken = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x",
                         ntohl(tokenBytes[0]), ntohl(tokenBytes[1]), ntohl(tokenBytes[2]),
                         ntohl(tokenBytes[3]), ntohl(tokenBytes[4]), ntohl(tokenBytes[5]),
                         ntohl(tokenBytes[6]), ntohl(tokenBytes[7])];

    [[MyModel sharedModel] setApnsToken:hexToken];
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution, since encondig bytes as hex, implies that you can count it ;)

Comment: On XCode 5 I had to cast the deviceToken to make it compile: const unsigned *tokenBytes = (const unsigned *)[deviceToken bytes];

Comment: um.. what's the point of converting it to hex? why not just save it as is?

Comment: I mean in ray wenderlich's [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) about sending push notifications, you simply copy the value of the device token from the iOS app and feed it to the push server as is, without any fancy pants hex conversion and all that stuff..

Comment: Curious, why do you use ntohl?

Comment: @abbood some push servers consume an NSString (without spaces) instead of NSData.

Comment: why's it being declared as `const`?

Comment: @IanDundas because `[deviceToken bytes]` returns a `const unsigned *`

Comment: Error: Cannot initialize a variable of type 'const unsigned int *' with an rvalue of type 'const void *'

Comment: Tokens are going to be larger than 32 bytes soon so this will need to be a loop over each byte, instead of eight hard-coded integers.

Comment: Would this be a better solution? `const unsigned *tokenBytes = [deviceToken bytes];
 NSMutableString *hexToken = [NSMutableString string];
 for (NSUInteger byteCount = 0; byteCount * 4 < [deviceToken length]; byteCount++) {
  [hexToken appendFormat:@"%08x", ntohl(tokenBytes[byteCount])];
 }`

Comment: `Important: APNs device tokens are of variable length. Do not hard-code their size.`
Apple says.

Comment: how to write this code in swift? I have objective c project and need to convert it to swift ...

Comment: this is madness

Answer (score 157):

You could use this

```
- (NSString *)stringWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    const char *data = [deviceToken bytes];
    NSMutableString *token = [NSMutableString string];

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [deviceToken length]; i++) {
        [token appendFormat:@"%02.2hhX", data[i]];
    }

    return [token copy];
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it is way more safe than using `description`.

Comment: This is the only correct answer in Objective-C that will handle the upcoming increase in the token size.

Comment: Agreed that this is probably the safest way as it doesn't assume any particular token size/length.

Comment: Works in iOS 10.

Comment: I've used `[token appendFormat:@"%02.2hhx", data[i]];` as Amazon SNS requires lower case.

Answer (score 42):

For those who want in **Swift 3** and most easier method

```
func extractTokenFromData(deviceToken:Data) -> String {
    let token = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})
    return token.uppercased();
}
```

Comment: I wrote the same code :) This is most swifty version, and only this works

Comment: @Anand can u please explain what is happing in this code `deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})`

Comment: It uses reduce function of swift that serialises Data into hexadecimal string and then to String. To understand more about reduce function read https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-guide-to-map-filter-reduce/

Answer (score 29):

Explanation of `%02.2hhx` in the high vote [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24979958/1260976):

- `%`: Introduces the `x` conversion specifier.
- `02`: The minimum width of the converted value is 2. If the converted value has fewer bytes than the field width, it shall be padded with `0` on the left.
- `.2`: Gives the minimum number of digits to appear for the `x` conversion specifier.
- `hh`: Specifies that the `x` conversion specifier applies to a signed char or unsigned char argument (the argument will have been promoted according to the integer promotions, but its value shall be converted to signed char or unsigned char before printing).
- `x`: The unsigned argument shall be converted to unsigned hexadecimal format in the style "dddd"; the letters "abcdef" are used. The precision specifies the minimum number of digits to appear; if the value being converted can be represented in fewer digits, it shall be expanded with leading zeros. The default precision is 1. The result of converting zero with an explicit precision of zero shall be no characters.

For more details, see the [IEEE printf specification](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html).

---

Based on the above explanation, I think it is better to change `%02.2hhx` to `%02x` or `%.2x`.

For Swift 5, the following methods are all feasible:

```
deviceToken.map({String(format: "%02x", $0)}).joined()
```

```
deviceToken.map({String(format: "%.2x", $0)}).joined()
```

```
deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02x", $1)})
```

```
deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%.2x", $1)})
```

The test is as follows:

```
let deviceToken = (0..<32).reduce(Data(), {$0 + [$1]})
print(deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%.2x", $1)}))
// Print content:
// 000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Does this work also with iOS 12? Or does it only depend on Swift version?

Comment: @Markus This works in iOS 12, only depends on Swift version.

Answer (score 17):

In iOS 13 the description will be in different format. Kindly use below code to fetch the device token.

```
- (NSString *)fetchDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSUInteger len = deviceToken.length;
    if (len == 0) {
        return nil;
    }
    const unsigned char *buffer = deviceToken.bytes;
    NSMutableString *hexString  = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:(len * 2)];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        [hexString appendFormat:@"%02x", buffer[i]];
    }
    return [hexString copy];
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution for ios 13. Thanks Vishnu

Comment: It doesn't compile currently - `length` in the for loop should be changed to `len`. Apparently a too small change for me to make an edit.. But else works perfectly!

Answer (score 13):

It's my solution and It works well in my app:

```
    NSString* newToken = [[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",deviceToken] 
stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

- convert `NSData` to `NSString` with `stringWithFormat`
- trim the "<>"
- remove the spaces

Comment: This just implicitly calls `-description`, so it isn't any safer than the accepted answer.

Comment: Can you please link your source? I can't find information about it anywhere. Thx.

Comment: Found it!
I think that it is a little different. Use the description attribute directly is not safe because it could change in future versions, but if you use it THROUGH a NSString method you will hardly have problems.

Comment: No this really calls `description` on deviceToken like jszumski says.

Comment: Hi Jonny, probably you misunderstand what I said in my previous comment: the `description` method can change, but if you use it through another method it will be safe because "they" will adapt it. Btw, every solution here uses the `description` field, directly or not, so if you have a better solution, we will be very thankful.

Comment: @Zeb It's not safe to rely on `description` whether you call it directly, or use it through another method, because the format of the returned string could be changed at any time. The correct solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16411517/108105

Answer (score 11):

I think converting deviceToken to hex byte string has no sense. Why? You will send it to your backend, where it will be transformed back to bytes to be pushed to APNS. So, use **NSData**'s method `base64EncodedStringWithOptions`, push it to server, and then use reverse base64decoded data :) That is so much easier :)

```
NSString *tokenString = [tokenData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed];
```

Comment: @jeet.chanchawat please do not add code to other users' answers.  We don't want to put words in their mouth, especially when adding Swift to an Objective-C answer.  Instead, add your own answer.

Comment: I just didn't wanted to plagiarise the @Oleg Shanyuk's answer. As it is just the translation in another language built upon his answer, So he deserves the future up votes. If I add another answer it will give me upvotes for the answer which is research of someone else. Hope this justifies the EDIT.

Answer (score 11):

In iOS 13 `description` will break so use this

```
let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined()
```

For clarity, let’s break this down and explain each part:

The map method operates on each element of a sequence. Because Data is a sequence of bytes in Swift, the passed closure is evaluated for each byte in deviceToken.
The String(format:) initializer evaluates each byte in the data (represented by the anonymous parameter $0) using the %02x format specifier, to produce a zero-padded, 2-digit hexadecimal representation of the byte / 8-bit integer.
After collecting each byte representation created by the map method, joined() concatenates each element into a single string.

P.S don't use description gives different string in iOS 12 and iOS 13 and not safe as per future scope. **Developers shouldn’t have relied on a specific format for an object’s description.**

```
// iOS 12
(deviceToken as NSData).description // "<965b251c 6cb1926d e3cb366f dfb16ddd e6b9086a 8a3cac9e 5f857679 376eab7C>"

// iOS 13
(deviceToken as NSData).description // "{length = 32, bytes = 0x965b251c 6cb1926d e3cb366f dfb16ddd ... 5f857679 376eab7c }"
```

For more information read [This](https://nshipster.com/apns-device-tokens/).

Comment: how to write this in javascript

Answer (score 6):

## 2020

token as text...

```
let tat = deviceToken.map{ data in String(format: "%02.2hhx", data) }.joined()
```

or if you prefer

```
let tat2 = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined()
```

(result is the same)

Answer (score 3):

This is a little bit shorter solution:

```
NSData *token = // ...
const uint64_t *tokenBytes = token.bytes;
NSString *hex = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%016llx%016llx%016llx%016llx",
                 ntohll(tokenBytes[0]), ntohll(tokenBytes[1]),
                 ntohll(tokenBytes[2]), ntohll(tokenBytes[3])];
```

Answer (score 3):

## Functional Swift version

One liner:

```
let hexString = UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>(start: UnsafePointer(data.bytes),
count: data.length).map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joinWithSeparator("")
```

---

Here's in a reusable and self documenting extension form:

```
extension NSData {
    func base16EncodedString(uppercase uppercase: Bool = false) -> String {
        let buffer = UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>(start: UnsafePointer(self.bytes),
                                                count: self.length)
        let hexFormat = uppercase ? "X" : "x"
        let formatString = "%02\(hexFormat)"
        let bytesAsHexStrings = buffer.map {
            String(format: formatString, $0)
        }
        return bytesAsHexStrings.joinWithSeparator("")
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, use `reduce("", combine: +)` instead of `joinWithSeparator("")` to be seen as a functional master by your peers.

---

Edit: I changed String($0, radix: 16) to String(format: "%02x", $0), because one digit numbers needed to having a padding zero

(I don't know yet how to mark a question as a duplicate of [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305225/best-way-to-serialize-a-nsdata-into-an-hexadeximal-string/35730103#35730103), so I just posted my answer again)

Comment: Works for me, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Throwing my answer on the pile. Avoid using string parsing; It's not guaranteed by the docs that NSData.description will always work that way.

Swift 3 Implementation:

```
extension Data {
    func hexString() -> String {
        var bytesPointer: UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8> = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: nil, count: 0)
        self.withUnsafeBytes { (bytes) in
            bytesPointer = UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>(start: UnsafePointer(bytes), count:self.count)
        }
        let hexBytes = bytesPointer.map { return String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }
        return hexBytes.joined()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work for you,

```
NSUInteger dataLength = deviceToken.length;
    
const unsigned char *dataBuffer = (const unsigned char *)deviceToken.bytes;
NSMutableString *deviceTokenString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:(dataLength * 2)];
for (int i = 0; i < dataLength; ++i) {
    [deviceTokenString appendFormat:@"%02x", dataBuffer[i]];
}
    
NSLog(@"The generated device token string is : %@",deviceTokenString);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to test two different methods with format `"%02.2hhx"` and `"%02x"`

```
    var i :Int = 0
    var j: Int = 0
    let e: Int = Int(1e4)
    let time = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
    while i < e {
        _ =  deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined()
        i += 1
    }
    let time2 = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
    let delta = time2-time
    print(delta)

    let time3 = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
    while j < e {
        _ =  deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02x", $1)})
        j += 1
    }
    let time4 = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
    let delta2 = time4-time3
    print(delta2)
```

and the result is that the fastest is `"%02x"` at average 2.0 vs 2.6 for the reduced version:

```
deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02x", $1)})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you do it in Xamarin.iOS

```
public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
{
    var tokenStringBase64 = deviceToken.GetBase64EncodedString(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.None);
    //now you can store it for later use in local storage
}
```

Comment: I'm new to this but it looks like you need Hexadecimal when sending to APNS so I am not sure why you are suggesting base64...

Answer (score 1):

Using [updateAccumulatingResult](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126956-reduce) is more efficient than the various other approaches found here, so here's the *Swiftiest* way to stringify your `Data` bytes:

```swift
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    let token = deviceToken.reduce(into: "") { $0 += String(format: "%.2x", $1) }
    print(token)
}
```

Comment: Alex, wouldn't it be %02.2hhx

Answer (score 0):

For Swift :

```
var characterSet: NSCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet( charactersInString: "<>" )
    var deviceTokenString: String = ( deviceToken.description as NSString )
    .stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet( characterSet )
    .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString( " ", withString: "" ) as String

println( deviceTokenString )
```

Answer (score 0):

**2023**

```
let tokenString = deviceToken.reduce("") { $0 + String(format: "%02.2hhx", $1) }
```

or:

```
let tokenString = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0)}.joined()
```

To learn more about why the format `02.2hhx` is suggested, you can read [this post on NSHipster](https://nshipster.com/apns-device-tokens/#overturned-in-ios-13) and [the IEEE specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html).

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString *tokenString = [[newDeviceToken description] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[<> ]" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [[newDeviceToken description] length])];
```

Comment: great solution
As of today, it can be implified to credentials.token.description.replacingOccurrences(of: "[<> ]", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)

Answer (score -1):

Swift:

```
let tokenString = deviceToken.description.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("[ <>]", withString: "", options: .RegularExpressionSearch, range: nil)
```

Answer (score -1):

What about one line solution?

Objective C

```
NSString *token = [[data.description componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet]invertedSet]]componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Swift

```
let token = data.description.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted).joined()
```

Comment: This is the simple and the best solution.  Thanks

Answer (score -2):

```
-(NSString *)deviceTokenWithData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSString *deviceToken = [[data description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    deviceToken = [deviceToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    return deviceToken;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Swift

```
    // make sure that we have token for the devie on the App
    func application(application: UIApplication
        , didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {

            var tokenStr = deviceToken.description
            tokenStr = tokenStr.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<", withString: "", options: [], range: nil)
            tokenStr = tokenStr.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(">", withString: "", options: [], range: nil)
            tokenStr = tokenStr.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "", options: [], range: nil)



            print("my token is: \(tokenStr)")

    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Use excellent category!

// .h file

```
@interface NSData (DeviceToken)

- (NSString *)stringDeviceToken;

@end
```

// .m file

```
#import "NSData+DeviceToken.h"

@implementation NSData (DeviceToken)

- (NSString *)stringDeviceToken {
    const unsigned *deviceTokenBytes = [deviceToken bytes];
    NSString *deviceToken = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x",
                     ntohl(deviceTokenBytes[0]), ntohl(deviceTokenBytes[1]), ntohl(deviceTokenBytes[2]),
                     ntohl(deviceTokenBytes[3]), ntohl(deviceTokenBytes[4]), ntohl(deviceTokenBytes[5]),
                     ntohl(deviceTokenBytes[6]), ntohl(deviceTokenBytes[7])];
    return deviceToken;
}
```

@end

// AppDelegate.m

```
#import "NSData+DeviceToken.h"

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    NSString *token = deviceToken.stringDeviceToken;
}
```

Works fine!

Comment: Do not rely on using "description", it's format could change in the future. It is for display purposes only.

Answer (score -3):

**Swift 3:**

If any one is looking for a way to get device token in Swift 3. Use the below modified snippet.

```
    let characterSet: CharacterSet = CharacterSet( charactersIn: "<>" )

    let deviceTokenString: String = (deviceToken.description as NSString)
        .trimmingCharacters(in: characterSet as CharacterSet)
        .replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
        .uppercased()

    print(deviceTokenString)
```

Comment: I don't recommend using .description as that is not guaranteed to remain the same. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372815/how-can-i-convert-my-device-token-nsdata-into-an-nsstring/39754930#39754930

Answer (score -4):

```
var token: String = ""
for i in 0..<deviceToken.count {
    token += String(format: "%02.2hhx", deviceToken[i] as CVarArg)
}

print(token)
```

Comment: Using description is not safe as it is not guaranteed to give same results in future.

Answer (score -4):

The solution @kulss posted here, while lacking in elegance but having the virtue of simplicity no longer works in iOS 13, since `description` will work differently for NSData. You can still use `debugDescription` though.

```
NSString * deviceTokenString = [[[[deviceToken debugDescription]
                     stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<" withString: @""] 
                    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString: @""] 
                   stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];
```

Answer (score -7):

Try this one unless the data is null-terminated.

`NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:newDeviceToken
                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Comment: I tried that one, it doesn't work. I have it commented out in my code snippet.

Comment: @SheehanAlam This guy made it through. Take a look how it's converting to string. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994302/didregisterforremotenotificationswithdevicetoken-doesnt-invoke-on-calling-regi

Answer (score -9):

```
NSString *tokenstring = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:token encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: This works when the data is a string, however, the deviceToken isn't a string.