# How to Get Device Token in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, token, devicetoken

I am calling device token in my first `viewcontroller`. And I cant get result because Device token is null. Here below is my code in `appdelegate`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge];

    return YES;
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    token = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:      [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"Device Token ---%@", token);
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:token forKey:@"DeviceToken"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

When I am calling in Viewcontroller :

```
NSString *token=  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"DeviceToken"];
```

token is null.

Comment: are you trying it on simulator?

Comment: Try with the real device.

Comment: Check your provisioning profiles and build in real device.

Answer (score 4):

```
    NSString *device = [deviceToken description];
    device = [device stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    device = [device stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

    NSLog(@"My device is: %@", device);
```

This worked perfectly for me in my device.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to Kulss' answer in this SO Answer:

[How can I convert my device token (NSData) into an NSString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372815/how-can-i-convert-my-device-token-nsdata-into-an-nsstring/9372848#9372848)

You should be parsing the bytes not the description.

Comment: This is definitely the correct answer. The other answers are suggesting solutions that may not be future proof.

Answer (score 1):

**First**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Add this in `Application.h`

Answer (score 0):

try this one my friend....

```
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken {
              #if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR

// Prepare the Device Token for Registration (remove spaces and < >)
token = [[[[devToken description]
                        stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<"withString:@""]
                       stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""]
                      stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];
NSLog(@"%@",token);
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:token forKey:@"deviceToken"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        #endif
}
/**
  * Failed to Register for Remote Notifications
 */
  - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
    #if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR

   NSLog(@"Error in registration. Error: %@", error);
  #endif
  }
```

Happy Coding!!!!

Comment: Thanks but im checking with real device . Please check my above comment.

Comment: this will work only for deivce my friend...check my line #if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR

Answer (score 0):

Add two methods didRegister and didFailToRegister, and confirm are u getting a call in didRegister or in didFailedToRegister.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    NSLog(@"Device Token=> %@",deviceToken);

    //Parse your device toke

}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error in registration. Error: %@", error.description);
}
```

and assure are u getting succesfully ur device token. Or u r failed to registerForRemote...

Comment: I  have added this method as well. And Im getting successfully. But the problem is that my viewcontroller is loading before than getting device token . For this ,device token is null? Is it more clear now?

Comment: why not u load ur viewcontroller after registering remote notification.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*) deviceToken {
    NSString *pushToken = [deviceToken description];
    pushToken = [pushToken stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:pushToken forKey:@"device_token_data"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be help you.

First register notification in then you will get toke in `didRegisterRemoteNotification`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {   
    self.strdeviceToken=[[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    self.strdeviceToken = [self.strdeviceToken stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    self.strdeviceToken=[self.strdeviceToken stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check your provisioning profile. Also the App should be configured for push notification on developer portal.
Perform these steps for doing so.

1. Enable push notification for your Application Identifier on Developer portal.
2. regenerate the provisioning profile.
3. Download and install new provisioning profile.
4. Build and run.
   It will work.

Answer (score 0):

try this one..

after your transactions completed, you want token number in the view controller. so for that try to make or change root view controller again in appDelegate by the method like this in `AppDelegate.m`.

```
-(void)changeRootView
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    //Adding navigation controller to the main view.
    [navigationController release];

    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
```

in this method

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

this statement is helped to call `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` again and you can store the token in some object like `NSUserDefaults` and you can use it in your viewController. It works for me. you can try this. Best luck.